# Hibernate model class and helper method best practices

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

Please consider the following (partial) class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "account", catalog = "storeman", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email"))
public class Account implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private String email;
    private String displayName;

    ...

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    @Column(name = "email", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 80)
    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    @Column(name = "display_name", nullable = false, length = 50)
    public String getDisplayName() {
        return this.displayName;
    }

    public static Account lookup(String email, Session session){
        return (Account)
                session.createCriteria(Account.class)
                .add(Restrictions.eq("email", email))
                .uniqueResult();
    }
}
```

As you can see, it maps the `account` table of mydb that uses `id` as the primary key. However, when searching for Account in db I want use the email as selection criteria. To do so I have added a static method named `lookup` that performs my query. That works fine as far as I can see.
However I would like to ask whether that kind of approach is good practice  when working with hibernate (dynamic web project using JDBC) or not and what kind of issues this can bring (if any).

Comment: i think this question belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that! Thanks I'll post the question there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing a `session` (or `EntityManager`, or pretty much any other service-object) around is not good practice in my book. Do this enough and you'll find yourself having trouble gathering and controlling where you call the database. The `Service`-objects should be the ones "using" the data-objects, not the other way around.

The correct thing to do is to create a `Repository`-service, which contains the means for getting the session/EntityManager, and also methods that perform the JPA-operations for this Entity/functional area.

So, I would move the query out of the Entity class, and into a Repository (the class where this method is called, the one that holds the session, sounds like a place to start.)

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you create a DAO class say AccountDAO for your model Account and move lookup method to AccountDAO.